# Stdout and stderror in CentOS

Tags: bash, shell, centos, stdout

I am exec command:

```
yum info mcrypt | grep -i error > /dev/null
yum info mcrypt | grep -i error 2> /dev/null
```

But i see:

> Error: No matching Packages to list

How I can hide this messasge from stdout?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

nohup commands > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Comment: Please explain how this solves your problem.

Comment: How is this related to the question? Yes you used `2>&1` as davidgo suggested two months ago. -- Combined in `>/dev/null 2>&1` it will discard both stdout and stderr. ...but how is the `nohup` and background execution `&` related?

Answer (score 3):

Its not exactly clear what you are trying to do - Why would you "grep" for an error message you don't want.

I suspect the problem you are having may be that you are diverting stderr after it has been displayed - you may want to be using

```
yum info mcrypt 2>/dev/null | grep -i "error"
```

Or, if you are simply wanting to ignore the error,

```
yum info mcryp3t 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you so mach.

But it not what i want.

i am using this expression to check avebility of yum package in my bash script.

Comment: $(yum info mcrypt | grep -i error)  2> /dev/null  the same

Comment: how about 'yum info mcrypt 2>&1 | grep "Name"'  or 'yum info mcrypt 2>&1 | grep "Name" | wc -l'